# Best practice with ClickOnce Deployment application settings

Tags: connection-string, clickonce, app-config

I have a question regarding a WinForm application and ClickOnce Deployment.

Currently, I use the Visual Studio Installer for creating my installer. One of the things that I do is I have created a custom installer class that I use for entering in certain information (servername, database name, username, password, port number - which is needing for my connection string to the DB).  This information gets written to my app config file. However, this makes updates a pain, so I am looking into ClickOnce Deployment instead.

For those of you that do something similar, what's the best way to go about handling this? Is it possible for me to include a config file with my ClickOnce Deployment project that will just copy the settings from that file during the installation? Or, what is the recommend best practice for handling this?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My ClickOnce application also accesses a database. I created a separate program that asks for the database information and encrypts it into a .DAT file. The .DAT file is added to the main program. You must change a setting on the file to Content so that it is included in deployment. The main program opens the .DAT file and decrypts it for the information. This way no one that uses the program knows any of the database information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That would be a pretty simple way to resolve that. Thanks again!